# Creating comma separated list from a list in c# without terminating comma

Tags: c#, string, list

I Have a list and I want to use its members in `IN` statement in C#.  using `string.Join`
 insert a comma at the end of the list which is not desired. what should I do?

```
 string sql = string.Format(@"SELECT I.ItemId FROM POS.Item I WHERE
I.Code IN ({0})", string.Join(",", code.ToArray()));
```

Comment: Show the data in code variable. thats not behaviour of join. join doesnt put , in the end

Comment: `String.Join` does not add `separator` at the end of the result. There has to be something different wrong with your code.

Comment: Do you have an empty string (or something that `.ToString`s to it) - or a `null` - in `code`?

Comment: @BenAllred: you are right!!! I Had an empty string and I didn't consider it

Comment: @fasadat: I just created an answer out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have an empty string or a null in `code`.

Look at this:

```
string joined = string.Join(",", new string[] { "asdf", "qwer", "" });
Console.WriteLine(joined);
```

or

```
string joined = string.Join(",", new string[] { "asdf", "qwer", null });
Console.WriteLine(joined);
```

Both give:

```
asdf,qwer,
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be empty string in your list that is why it adds extra comma at the end of string otherwise string.Join will never add extra comma. If this is the case then you should remove that extra comma by [TrimEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function like

```
string sql = string.Format(@"SELECT I.ItemId FROM POS.Item I WHERE
I.Code IN ({0})", string.Join(",", code.ToArray()).TrimEnd(','));
```